# Can Kafka brokers connect through more than one port

Tags: apache-kafka

We have quite a few micro-services connecting to a cluster of Kafka brockers as a enterprise message bus.
Part of our resiliency testing we want to test how a given system recovers from infrastructure failure and we use Gremlin for this purpose. If we want to simulate a Kafka failure Gremlin will cut off the network connection to port 9092 which is the port Kafka communicates through.
The issue with this is that when cutting off the networking on that port all our micro-services connecting to Kafka are impacted not only the one we want to test.
One idea would be to have Kafka expose more than one port, say 9092 and 9093 and have our app connecting via 9092 whereas all other micro-services will keep running via 9093.

I don't know if this is possible and this is my question about.
If this is not possible, what other ideas to achieving what we want would you have.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kafka `listeners` server config can bind the server to multiple ports, yes, but this is not for a multiplexing use case as you seem to be asking for. `bootstrap.servers` should only connect to one host:port, per server, as a CSV list. Rather, this is used to expose different protocols like SSL / SASL_SSL / SASL_PLAINTEXT, etc

> all our micro-services connecting to Kafka are impacted not only the one we want to test

Unclear if you're cutting off the network at the router, or at the app, or from one broker. If at the broker, then sounds like you've not setup replication factors correctly on some topics, as Kafka clients will always reconnect to in sync partition leaders

Comment: We will cut the network at broker level and yes the clients will reconnect. The issue is that ALL THE CLIENTS will reconnect not only the app we are trying to test. But after making some more research I agree your only one host:port per protocol is correct thus accepting your answer.

Comment: The clients should reconnect to an in sync replica (other broker) if they fail to connect to the active leader, but Zookeeper/Raft is used for leader election, so you'd have to terminate connections between servers as well, not only traffic from clients, assuming you're using firewall rules to drop packets between IP addresses